# Play! Framework 1.2 deploy error: NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

Tags: java, groovy, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm running a play! framework 1.2.7 in a server with the following dependencies:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play 1.2.7
    - play -> secure
    - play -> crud
    - play -> press 1.0.36
    - localModule -> YoutubeVideosCRUD 0.2

repositories: 
    - local repo:
        type: local
        artifact: "${application.path}/local-repo/[module]-[revision].zip"
        contains:
            - localModule -> *
```

As I'm not root in the server I have copied and unzipped play-1.2.7.zip in a sibbling directory of my application and then created a soft like this, standing in `/var/www/clients/[..]/web/Application`:

```
ln -s /var/www/clients/[..]/web/play-1.2.7/play play
```

When I run `./play start --%server` I get the following output on the log:

```
10:27:19,372 INFO  ~ Starting /var/www/clients/[...]/web/Application
10:27:19,373 INFO  ~ Module secure is available (/var/www/clients/[...]/web/play-1.2.7/modules/secure)
10:27:19,373 INFO  ~ Module press is available (/var/www/clients/[...]/web/play-1.2.7/modules/press-1.0.36)
10:27:19,373 INFO  ~ Module crud is available (/var/www/clients/[...]/web/play-1.2.7/modules/crud)
10:27:19,373 INFO  ~ Module YoutubeVideosCRUD is available (/var/www/clients/[...]/web/Application/modules/YoutubeVideosCRUD-0.2)
10:27:20,595 INFO  ~ Precompiling ...
10:27:29,165 ERROR ~ Cannot start in PROD mode with errors
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberMetaMethod.<clinit>(NumberNumberMetaMethod.java:90)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.createMetaMethodFromClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:212)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:86)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:61)
   at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:29)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:49)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
   at groovy.lang.Binding.<init>(Binding.java:34)
   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.<init>(GroovyShell.java:62)
   at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.<clinit>(GroovyTemplate.java:77)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:78)
   at play.templates.TemplateLoader.scan(TemplateLoader.java:222)
   at play.templates.TemplateLoader.scan(TemplateLoader.java:237)
   at play.templates.TemplateLoader.scan(TemplateLoader.java:237)
   at play.templates.TemplateLoader.getAllTemplate(TemplateLoader.java:205)
   at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:608)
   at play.Play.init(Play.java:304)
   at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:162)
```

(some parts of the directory have been stripped)

I can't seem to find what's happening. I have found that [https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691234/260389]:

```
A NoClassDefFoundError specifies that a class was available during compile time, but missing during runtime.
```

But I can't seem to link that to a solution to my problem.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I found the problem. The problem was that the java compiler that we were using was the GNU compiler for java 5. I changed it for **sun java 7** and it worked like a charm.